# Can't rename folders or files on mobile devices

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, rename, activesync

Since Windows 8 is running on my notebook (clean install, no upgrade), I can't rename folders or files on mobile devices running Windows Mobile or CE and connected with ActiveSync (via USB) anymore (or even create new ones with a custom name). The explorer will ignore my input and use the previously entered name (or something like "New Folder" for newly created directories).

**Step 1:** Right click in Explorer > New Folder > Enter a name

[image]

**Step 2:** Confirm with enter key

[image]

Does anyone have a clue on how to fix that?

*UPDATE*

The devices are shown in Explorer like this:

[image]

**Update:** Neither upgrading to Windows 8.1 nor reinstalling Windows 8.1 changed the behavior described above.

Comment: So you are able to create files on these devices?  Are you able to rename the folders/files through the command prompt?

Comment: I can't rename files either - updated the question. I don't know how to navigate to the device on the command prompt.

Comment: Do you navigate to the device's storage using explorer?

Comment: After connecting the devices via USB, the Mobile Device Center pops up and I can access the device as a `Portable Device` in the Windows Explorer. That's were I'd like to rename/create some folders.

Comment: So the device is assigned a drive letter I presume?

Comment: No, there's just a node for the device in the explorer.

Comment: apparently there is no solution. since 2013 http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-files/windows-8-unable-to-rename-files-on-pocket-pc/abae21b7-7ee1-41c7-853e-1ac7ea5b0413

Comment: This is still a problem in Windows 10 when the device is connected with Windows Mobile Device Center instead of ActiveSync. I may decide to stick to Windows 7 because of this.